# DataGridView and SQL query name

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have a function that gets all the data from database (also the column names) and shows it in a DataGridView.

The problem is that the DataGrid show also the column name. How can I edit the columns name? I already tried

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "xxx";
```

without success.

```
private void PriceChange_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      DbCards d = new DbCards();

      dataGridView1.DataSource = d.GetAllcards().Tables[0];
}
```

`GetAllcards()` is `select * from Cards`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText` instead

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the header text displayed by a DataGridViewColumn you need to use the [HeaderText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.headertext(v=vs.110).aspx) property

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "xxx";
```